# Asynchronous vs. Synchronous data transmission speed

Tags: digital-modes

Humans are asynchronous receivers, they can pick up words at any time, even if spread out, can combine into a sentence. Data rates are as fast as someone can hear/talk/copy code.

All of the fast digital modes are Synchronous, example the HF digital voice has a lag between someone talking and their voice getting out because of the initial sync code.

On a particular [radio Wikipedia page](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/AN/PRC-148), it claimed these data rates:

> AM/FM Synchronous: 12/16 kbit/s
>
> AM/FM Asynchronous: Below 4800 Baud

What aspect of digital technology allows the data rate to be much faster if the transmission is synchronous.

Comment: Looks like it is an expensive radio.

Comment: I don't even think it is for sale other than the military

Comment: Oops, sorry about that, I found it on the Wikipedia page for the radio. Edited to add the correct link. Where I found the data rate information.

Answer (score 3):

Wikipedia is plain bonkers. The [manufacturer's data sheet](http://www.thalescomminc.com/datasheets/Thales%20MBITR.pdf) is more enlightening:

> **Waveforms/Modes of Operation**
>
> Implemented and Planned
>
> - AM/FM
>
>   - Non-secure voice
>   - Non-secure narrowband voice (FM)
>   - **12 and 16 kbps secure voice**
>   - **12 and 16 kbps secure synchronous data**
>   - **Secure asynchronous data to 4800 bps**

[...]

> - ANDVT
>
>   - Secure narrowband voice (LPC-10, MELP Vocoders)
>   - **Secure 2400 bps synchronous data**

Notice it says "bps" and "kbps" which mean "(kilo) bits per second". There is no "[baud](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baud)" anywhere in the spec sheet. Whoever wrote that Wikipedia article must not know [the difference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20534417/1574959).

Secondly, we can't infer from any of this that synchronous communications are faster than asynchronous communications. All we can infer is that this particular radio implements a number of modes. Some are fast, and some are slow. Some are synchronous, and some are asynchronous. You can even see that the *slowest* data listed in the datasheet is ANDVT, and it is described as "synchronous".